# Angular Material Input Box background color

Tags: angular, input

I am new to Angular and Material UI. I have a login screen working fine. The only challenge is when the user comes to the login page again and the browser prefills the input boxes there is a background color behind the text. Is there a way I can remove that background color?

[See in User name in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKTq2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I just found that I am insert the following in my css and it goes away.

input:-webkit-autofill {
  -         webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset;
           }

Hopefully if someone else runs into it the above should help